# Python - Twitter bot that retweets based on 'x' number of retweets

Tags: python, twitter

so I'm working on my first ever code for a simple Twitter bot that retweets based on hashtags. What I want to do is add a bit of code which will still allow the bot to retweet tweets that have one the hashtags specified but also ensure that the tweets have an X number of retweets already, to stop the bot tweeting small personal accounts that have little to no interactions.

Here is the code I've got so far which is working, just retweeting everyone and anyone that uses one of the hashtags:

```
import tweepy

from time import sleep

from keys import *

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#bcafc OR #hcafc OR #rufc OR #lufc OR #mot OR #alaw OR #twitterblades OR #sufc OR #forgedinsteel OR #swfc OR #swfcLIVE OR #notjustagame OR #youreds OR #utb OR #boro OR #htafc OR #drfc').items():

try:

    print('\Yorkshire Footy Bot found tweet by @' + tweet.user.screen_name + '. ' + 'Attempting to retweet.')


    tweet.retweet()


    print('Retweet published successfully.')


    sleep(20)


except tweepy.TweepError as error:

    print('\nError. Retweet not successful. Reason: ')

    print(error.reason)


except StopIteration:

    break
```

If there is no way to do this would it be possible to only retweet from accounts the bot follows? Even that would help limit the random tweets it's sending out.

Comment: There are specific rules around what content you should retweet, and how, in the developer policy -> https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation

Comment: Cheers mate, we’re already familiar with this I promise. The bot is only going to run for around ten minutes on Monday afternoon for a presentation then it will be gracefully retired.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [the documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-show-id) you'll see that Twitter gives you a lot of metadata about a Tweet.

You've correctly identified that `tweet.user.screen_name` gives you the user's name.

In a similar fashion, you can use `tweet.retweet_count` to see how many times a Tweet has been retweeted.

You could use

`for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#....').items():
   if tweet.retweet_count > 10:
      ...`

But, as Andy has said, please don't build a bot which just mindlessly retweets others.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, it’s only going to run for a short time during a presentation on Monday, just to prove it works, then it will be gracefully retired. I can assure you it’s not to spam, we just had to build a business case around ‘something we made’.